# Convert QVector<char*> list into a QStringList

Tags: qt, qt4

How can I convert a `QVector<char*>` to a `QStringList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way.

```
QVector<char*> vector;
QStringList list;
foreach (const char * str, vector) {
    list << str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try do it in this way (it works for me if I have a `QVector<QString>`):

```
QVector<char*> vector_char;
QStringList myStringList = vector_char.toList();
```

This code has to work as `QStringList` has inherited members of `QList`.

Here is somenthing in the documentation: [QVector documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvector.html#toList).

And that is all. 
I hope it can help you.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get an error saying "no viable conversion from 'QList<char *>' to 'QStringList'".